# Cannot access native WpfButton in UI Test, get Exception: System.NotSupportedExceptions

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to access a native Wpf control property within the UI test framework (MS UI Tests). My specific issue is that, when I try accessing a WpfButton control property (e.g., IsVisible) using the function call WpfButtonObject.GetProperty("IsVisible"), the exception "System.NotSupportedExceptions" occurs. I'm able to see this WpfButton property using Snoop; so, I'm wondering if the GetProperty call is correct? Please see my related code below. Thanks for any insight.

UIMap.cs: Test function for a pressing a WpfButton. Please note the call uIButton.GetPropery("IsVisible"). This is where the exception occurs:

```
public void PressButtonTest()
    {
        WpfButton uIButton = this.UIMainWindowWindow.UIButtonButton;
        object state = uIButton.GetProperty("IsVisible"); // Throws SystemNotSupportedException exception
        bool stateBool = (bool)state;
        Assert.IsTrue(stateBool, "Button is visible");
        PressButton();
    }
```

UIMap.Designer.cs: WpfButton property:

```
public WpfButton UIButtonButton
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIButtonButton == null))
            {
                this.mUIButtonButton = new WpfButton(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUIButtonButton.SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "button";
                this.mUIButtonButton.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIButtonButton;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done:

```
Point point;
bool isClickable = uIButton.TryGetClickablePoint(out point);
Assert.IsTrue(isClickable, "No clickable point was found, button not visible.");
```

By the way, your message in your Assert (2nd parameter) is inaccurate because it's only used on fail... in your case, when the button would not be visible. So in your output it would say "Button is visible" on failure when in fact it was not.